# I dont' understand with “not” in full text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I don't understand why I'm getting these results with my full-text search query in SQL Server 2014.

The following query returns results with "Supervisor" in the `Title` field and "Tokyo" in the `HTML_Description` field.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([post], (Title, HTML_Description), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

If I remove the `HTML_Description` field in the `CONTAINSTABLE` like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post 
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(post, (Title), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

The result is the same.

If I use only the `HTML_Description` field in the `CONTAINSTABLE` like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post 
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(post, (HTML_Description), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

There aren't any results.

How can I apply the `NOT` operator to all fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does this happen?** Because even when searching across multiple columns, the full text search conditions must be satisfied *within a single column*. Thus your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([post], (Title), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    * 
FROM post
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([post], (HTML_Description), 'Supervisor AND NOT Tokyo') 
        AS tb1 ON tb1.[Key] = post.ID
```

**Ways to work around this:**

You should combine `Title` and `HTML_Description` into a single column (you can even create a computed column to do this) and create the full text index on this column.

Worth mentioning: In most cases you can rewrite the query using 2 or more `CONTAINSTABLE` or `CONTAINS` statements to search each keyword individually -- `CONTAINS(*, 'apples') and CONTAINS(*, 'oranges')` instead of `CONTAINS(*, 'apples AND oranges')` -- but then you'll either get multiple meaningless `Rank` columns (because each is calculated against a single keyword) or you won't get a `Rank` at all (if you use `CONTAINS`). The link below shows a simple example of this. However this doesn't apply to your case because of your use of NOT. You cannot perform a full text search using only a NOT condition -- `CONTAINS(*, 'NOT Tokyo')` will throw an error.

See [Full-Text Search Queries with CONTAINS Clause Search Across Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294809)