# Building TSQL Full Text Search XOR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, containstable

I've got a table with the following texual data:

1. Linker been
2. Linker pagina
3. Rechter pagina

I'm using a `CONTAINSTABLE`. When I use the following full text expression  `"Linker*" AND "pagina*"` only the second record is returned.

I've tried building an XOR by using expression `("Linker*" OR "pagina*") AND NOT (  "pagina*" AND  "Linker*")`, but all records are returned.

Why?

Comment: When you say *"only the second record is returned"*, were you expecting something different? The 2nd result is what should have been returned.

Comment: Also, I'm not able to reproduce the behavior of your XOR expression -- my result set includes only the 1st and 3rd records. Maybe your FT index is out of sync with the data and you need to [repopulate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx)?

Comment: The correct result of the XOR should be 1,3 ... I expressed this in the example in Answer

Comment: Also if there are multiple columns in your full text index, [using `NOT` will result in unexpected behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062970/i-dont-understand-with-not-in-full-text-search);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(data,*,'("Linker*" OR "pagina*") AND NOT (  "pagina*" AND  "Linker*")') AS Results
```

Returned this to me:
[image]

You can also try "AND NOT" the CONTAINSTABLE of the AND itself as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(data,*,'"Linker*" OR "pagina*"') AS Results
WHERE Results.[KEY] NOT IN
(SELECT [Key] FROM CONTAINSTABLE(data,*,'"Linker*" AND "pagina*"'))
```

This is the return:
[image]

Comment: It is possible to do in one statement? The given example is a simplification of the complex query that is done.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker , the first statement is just one statement and it is working fine and returns the same result

Comment: Looks like the problem has to do with other columns. I'll look further into my data-set.